# Bootstrap Toggle: One on the rest off

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am using the Bootstrap Toggle plugin which converts checkboxes into toggle buttons.

When I change the toggle state from off to on, I want all others to toggle off.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" class="toggle" id="toggle-one">  
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" class="toggle" id="toggle-two">
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" class="toggle" id="toggle-three">

$('#toggle-one').bootstrapToggle('on');
$('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle('off');
$('#toggle-three').bootstrapToggle('off');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(".toggle").change(function() {
 if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  $('[id^="toggle"]').not(this).each(function() {
   $(this).bootstrapToggle('off');
  });
 }
});
```

What I am trying to do is, except current element, I am making off to all other elements.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knvnx2ks/1/) link

Comment: Works great, but the function only runs once, I can't change again

Comment: Do you want, if off then all other should on and vice versa ?

Comment: Just one on at a time, others off

Comment: The original function does what I want it to do, but only lets me run it once. Any ideas?

Comment: so the idea is, which ever is on other should be off right ?

Comment: and whichever is off other should be on is it right ?

Comment: they can all be off, just only one at a time turned on

Comment: Once check jsfiddle link and I made changes in code too. PLease go through it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137820/discussion-between-rahul-m-and-melissa-doll).

Answer (score 2):

You want your toggle buttons to behave more like `radio` rather than `checkbox`, so why not just convert them all to `radio`?

```
<input type="radio" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success"
    class="toggle mytoggle" id="toggle-one">
```

As for the jQuery part, here's something that works (an alternative if `$('.toggle').bootstrapToggle('off')` fails):

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).find('input.toggle').removeClass('off');

  $('.toggle').not(this).each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('off');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
  }); /*END each*/

  $(this).removeClass('off');
  $(this).addClass('btn-success');
}) /*END click*/
```

## JSFiddle demo here.

Answer (score 1):

Change the JQuery selector to select by the element's `class` rather than by the element's `ID`:

toggle

```
$('.toggle').bootstrapToggle('on');
```

or

```
$('.toggle').bootstrapToggle('off');
```